# Displaying text with '<b>' tags as html

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, wysiwyg

How do I display my string that is: `<b>test</b>` as: **test** in my html page?
I'm getting the string from my database, which was created with a wysiwyg editor.

I've tried using razor syntax:

```
@Html.Encode(Model.teststring);
```

But this doesn't work.

I've also tried using javascript, which didn't work either:

```
<div id="@Model.ID">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#@Model.ID').html(Model.teststring);
   </script>
</div>
```

Both show the text as follows: `<b>test</b>`

Is there a way to fix my problem?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Model.teststring)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place it within the `Html.Raw()`  like below

```
@Html.Raw(Model.teststring)
```

This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which renders unencoded HTML. You can find out more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your ID-naming:

1. Don't use the @-character and
2. Don't use the dot-character (.)

This seems to work well:

```js
var Model = {
  teststring: '<b>test</b>'
};
$('#ModelID').html(Model.teststring);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ModelID">
</div>
```